# Choosing right preposition before "top management"

Tags: prepositions

I can't decide which preposition is right for this case. At, in, other? Is there some rule for this? Could you help me, please?

> ... and shows that mistakes are being made also **at** (the?) top management.

Whole paragraph as requested below:

> Thank you for your comments, guys! I'm adding a whole paragraph: After several discussions, we decided to publish our project. “A project which restores COMPANY's credibility and shows that mistakes are being made also in top management. However, the important thing here (comma needed?) is how we handle these (those?) mistakes. In this article, we present one possible solution of how could COMPANY go back to their purpose/vision/mission (doesn't matter now)”

Thank you!

Comment: You need to provide more context. Based on the fragment you provided, I'd lean towards _by_.

Comment: ... and shows that mistakes are being made also ***at top management level***.

Comment: @Curiosity Site comments are considered ephemeral, and they are sometimes deleted without much notice. It would be better to edit the paragraph into the question.

Comment: "by top management".  You could say "at top management level" but the word "level" adds no information.  But it does diffuse responsibility a little, which may be what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A project which restores COMPANY's credibility and shows that mistakes were also being made ***at*** the top management level.

or

> A project which restores COMPANY's credibility and shows that mistakes were also being made ***by*** top management.

*Also* comes before the verb.

Referring to *the top management level* puts a bit of distance between the company and the people actually making the mistakes. If you only want to change the preposition, I'd go with *by*.

> However, the important thing here is how we handle those mistakes.

You wouldn't set *the important thing here* off with a comma because that's the subject of the sentence.

The difference between *these* and *those* is the distance from the speaker. Since the company is trying to change and put metaphorical distance between it and its mistakes, *those* would fit better there.

[Definition of by (#11)](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/by)

[These vs those](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/pronouns/that-these-and-those)

Comment: Thanks, this is a great explanation. Yes, I'd like to point at specific department in the company, which lead them to ...